# Scripts Not Serving to Browser Window

Tags: javascript, src

My challenge in creating a todo's application for a JS course is to use scripts to create new elements and `textContent`, and then serve to browser. My scripts are creating the elements, but not displaying the text in the browser.

```js
const todos = [{
        title: 'make bed',
        completed: true
    }, {
        title: 'shower',
        completed: false
    }, {
        title: 'shave',
        completed: true
    }, {
        title: 'feed the cat',
        completed: false
    }, {
        title: 'crush the day',
        completed: false
    }]

    const incompleteTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
        return !todo.completed
    })

    const summary = document.createElement('h2')
    summary.textContext = `You have ${incompleteTodos.length} todos left`
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(summary)
    todos.forEach(function (todo) {
              
        const p = document.createElement('p')
        p.textContent = 'todo.text'
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(p)

    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <script src ="todos-app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: BrowserView + Elements]

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your script in the header with the defer attribute:

```html
<head>
  <script src="todos-app.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

This way you are sure the entire page (including the body) exists when the script runs.

Comment: Let me know if this works, if not I'll take a better look at your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The 'Defer' attribute has not solved the problem. I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change your "todo.text" value to a proper value your array of todos has. In this case you are simply passing the string with the wrong value and it can be fixed by this:

```js
const todos = [{
        title: 'make bed',
        completed: true
    }, {
        title: 'shower',
        completed: false
    }, {
        title: 'shave',
        completed: true
    }, {
        title: 'feed the cat',
        completed: false
    }, {
        title: 'crush the day',
        completed: false
    }]

    const incompleteTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
        return !todo.completed
    })

    const summary = document.createElement('h2')
    summary.textContext = `You have ${incompleteTodos.length} todos left`
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(summary)
    todos.forEach(function (todo) {
              
        const p = document.createElement('p')
        p.textContent = `${todo.title}`
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(p)

    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <script src ="todos-app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You simply need to pass `todo.title` instead of `todo.text` since that's what you have defined your value of the object as and it needs to be within `template literals` with placeholders ( ${} )  for the value to show up instead of a simple `string literal`.

Read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)